# How to add an option button in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have the following code:

```
public void startDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.setType("start");
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "startDatePicker");
}
```

with DatePickerFragment

```
    private String type = "none";

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "works?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (type.equals("start")) {
        EditText e = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.date_of_task);
        e.setText("");
    } else {
        EditText e = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.deadlineDate);
        e.setText("");
    }
    super.onCancel(dialog);
}

public void setType(String t) {
    type = t;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    if (type.equals("start")) {
        EditText e = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.date_of_task);
        e.setText("" + day + "." + (month + 1) + "." + year);
    } else {
        EditText e = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.deadlineDate);
        e.setText("" + day + "." + (month + 1) + "." + year);
    }
}
```

My Problem is now that onCancel doesn't work. Therefore I want to add a Button on the DialogFragment which causes the action in onCreate. How can I add a button or how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug with the date/time pickerdialog. it is something like this :

now :
click on OK - the date gets set twice
click cancel - the date gets cleared then set
click back - date gets set once

expected :
click OK - date gets set once
click Cancel - date gets reset
click back - ntng and it retains the state as it was

As a work-around, you could keep a counter that would get set the first time you call the OnDateSetListener and if the counter is > 1 then return and reset counter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've solved my Problem with setting the method "setButton2" of the DatePickerDialog. I generated an OnclickListener and put my code into the onClick Method and it works